# Draw a closed self loop in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing a closed self loop which has a drop shape. The following is something I want.

[image]

I found some tikz code, but it didn't really work as I wanted. I want the loop to be closed on the top.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, every loop/.style={}]
\draw [fill] (0, 0) circle [radius=0.02];
\node [draw=none] {} edge [in=-50,out=-130,loop] ();
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your node has a certain size, and the loop is drawn from its edge. Set `inner sep` and `outer sep` to zero, and you'll avoid that. Below is a slightly different version, with just a `\node`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, every loop/.style={}]
\node [fill=black,circle,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] {} edge [in=-50,out=-130,loop] ();
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Second version

As LoopSpace mentions, it's easily done without a `node` at all, e.g.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\fill (0,0) circle[radius=1pt];
\draw (0,0)  to[in=-50,out=-130,loop] (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have beaten me by one second with exactly the same answer!

Comment: @Astrinus Oops, sorry about that. That has happened to me as well.

Comment: The node is overkill, just draw the path.  `\draw[scale=3] (0,0) to[out=-130,in=-50,loop] (0,0);`

Comment: @LoopSpace Hm, good point, thanks. Will edit.

Comment: Just be glad I didn't mention `hobby` ...